# Where does Adobe Fonts (aka Typkekit aka Creative Cloud Fonts) store fonts on my Mac?

Tags: macos, fonts, adobe, typekit

When a font is activated through Adobe Fonts, where does it get stored on my computer?

And why doesn't it show up in Font Book?

**Background:**
I recently ran into a situation where I was trying to verify that my CSS @font-family tags were working correctly. I opened Font Book to verify that I did NOT have the font already installed, then proceeded to open my HTML file in Chrome. Everything looked great! But it turned out that I *DID* have the font installed via Adobe Fonts. So my test was invalid and unfortunately my tags were not setup correctly.

Comment: Creative Cloud Fonts and Typekit are not really the same things. If you have a typekit subscription, your website loads fonts _from Typekit_ based on script tags with identifiers for your web property. Creative Cloud Fonts is a service for fonts on _local systems_ that are made available in Adobe products, but may 100% absolutely not be used for webfont purposes.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The fonts are located on your machine in the following folders:

Mac:
`/Users/<your user name>/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CoreSync/plugins/livetype/.r`

Windows: `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CoreSync\plugins\livetype\r`

You likely need to make sure you can see hidden/invisible files.

Comment: Yes! Too bad Adobe moderators block any posts on their forums with this info!

Comment: Good find! To add to this, I sorted my `r` folder [Windows] by date, then went 1-by-1 through each file, edited w/ Notepad++, until I found which font(s) I needed within each [font-family] group. Then copied that file to desktop, gave it an extension of `.otf`, installed the file and converted to `.woff` and `.woff2` for web use

Comment: You can see the font manifest in `livetype/c/entitlements.xml` -- that contains the numerical ID that goes with each named font.

Comment: Small fix on the path @ZachB says: it should be `livetype/.c/entitlements.xml`

Comment: in my case the fonts were in various subfolders of `livetype/`, so you may have to dig around a bit.

Answer (score 22):

To copy all Adobe fonts to your Downloads directory, and automatically rename them to something meaningful, you can check out my repo: https://github.com/Kalaschnik/adobe-fonts-revealer

The script is working like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice script! I always think it's clever when people put unicode emojis in their script.

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: That's a must have! Thank you very much

Comment: I love this. THANK YOU!

Comment: I have followed the installation instruction, but then running 'sh reveal' returns the 'no such file or directory' error. Do I need to be in some specific place with 'cd'? 
I am on macOS 12.6.7, the Terminal is set to its default ZSH. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the files in the `core sync` folder, and I copied my fonts to use in a local environment.

Few hours later, this folder has disappeared without any reason. I tried to get display the hidden files in Mac, didn't work.

To get the file, I used `bash cd`command and opened it in finder. Hope that helps.
...`cd "Application Support"` ... `open livetype`.

Answer (score -14):

I work at Adobe Fonts and I'm happy to clear things up here. I'm sorry you ran into this.

First, when fonts are activated/installed with Adobe Fonts, they won't show up in Font Book as these fonts managed through our site and Creative Cloud.

You can remove or temporarily deactivate them to make sure you're seeing the web fonts: https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/kb/troubleshoot-font-activation.html#5ToggletheAdobeFontssetting

Also, when possible, we use a different font-family name format to avoid this very issue. You can always check to make sure you're using our font-family name in your CSS/web project to be sure: https://fonts.adobe.com/my_fonts#web_projects-section

I hope this helps!

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: This doesn't really help him out--he needs to know where the actual font file is.  There is a number of reasonable reasons to need the actual font file--like using ImageMagick or some other library that doesn't support Creative Cloud's font system.